# How to create cornered edged shape with css?

Tags: css, shapes

I wish to create a shape like a rectangle but with one corner edited, I wish to create a site like the one below, how would I create the shapes shown?
 [image]

Here's a simpler image

[image]

How would I create the above image in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Just took a simple search:

http://codepen.io/pouretrebelle/pen/pbwIj

I think this is what you need?

Comment: Please don't just include links as an aswer; what if that URL goes down? Please summarize the information as needed to answer the question (and also cite your source, as you have done).

Answer (score 0):

Just found out, here's how to do it;

CSS;

```
.box {
background: #333;
/*fallback*/
background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 20px, #333 20px);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 300px;
width: 700px;
}

p {
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
p:last-child {
margin: 0;
}
```

then add this to the html;

```
<div class="box">

</div>
```